# Pinch Zoom with gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery, pinch, zooming

I'm trying to combine the capability of doing image zoom/panning 
inside of a Gallery view. The problem is controlling which touch 
events are processed by each. In a horizontal drag on the image, the 
ImageView needs to process the drag in order to pan, up until the edge 
of the image is reached then the gallery view needs to process the 
touch event so that it can swipe over to the next photo. 
It seems that if I return false from the imageview's ontouchevent, 
then I won't be notified of the panning-drag move events. 
What I tried to do was return true from the imageview's ontouchevent 
until the edge of the image was hit then return false. However I 
believe that this doesn't cause the Gallery to begin processing these 
events, as it missed the initial touchdown event. 
My next thought is to somehow turn the containing activity into the 
touch handler, and somehow stop the Gallery and ImageView from getting 
touch events normally, and have the activity forward the touch event's 
manually. Not sure if this is possible or if there is an example. 
My last resort will be to simply not use the android.widget.Gallery, 
which I want to avoid because I want the widget to "feel" the same as 
other places on the phone, and I like code re-use. Unfortunately I 
might have to do this, as I see all other apps that have this zoom/pan 
capability don't seem to use the Gallery widget (Gallery3D etc). 
My question is, what's the best way to design for this situation where 
motionevents need to split between two views? Any ideas would be 
greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: its a tough task to explain here.. paste you code here so that anyone can help you to figure it out.. ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please follow the links here.

http://jmsliu.com/138/android-infinite-loop-gallery.html